# Java moving file while writing consistent

Tags: java, file-io, operating-system

my java application is supposed to read logging data of a Snort application on a Debian server.
The Snort application runs independent from my evaluation app and writes his logs into a file.
My evaulation app is supposed to check just the new content every 5 minutes. That's why I will move the logfile, so that the Snort application has to create a new file while my app can check the already written data from the old one.

Now the question: How can I ensure that I don't destroy the file in the case, that I move it in the moment the Snort application is writing on it? Has Java a functionality to check the current actions for the file so that no data can get lost? Does the OS lock the file while writing?

Thanks for your help, Kn0rK3

Comment: Any feedback on my answer?  Please accept it if it helped you out.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you are looking for, but I would do this in a very different way. Either by recording the line number / timestamp of the last entry read from the log file or the position in a [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html) (the second option is more efficient for obvious reasons), and, the next time you read the file, only do it from the recorded position to the `EOF` (at which you can record the last read position again).

Also, you can replace the "pool every 5 minutes" to a "pool every time I get a [update notification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)" for this file strategy.

Since I assume that you don't have control of the code of the "Snort" application, I don't think that NIO [FileLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html)s will help you.

Comment: That's true. I have no control about the code of the Snort application.
And to read it every time it is updated isn't a good idea. The Snort app is a network control application for a local university network. It is possible that there are many writing actions in a minute.

Comment: I see, so it might be best to keep a pooling time like you are doing. But for the first part, I think that the cost of doing a position lookup with a RandomAccessFile is negligible, and you can open the file as read only.

Answer (score 1):

It should not be an issue.  Typically a logging application has some sort of file-descriptor or stream open to a file.  If the file gets renamed, that doesn't affect the writing application in any way -- the name is independent to the contents of the file or its location on disk.  Snort should continue to write to the new file-name until it notices that the file has been renamed at which point it re-opens a new log file to the old-name and switches to writing to that one.

That's the whole reason why it reopens in the first place.  To support this sort of mechanism.

> Now the question: How can I ensure that I don't destroy the file in the case...

The only thing you have to worry about is that you are renaming the file to a file-name that does not already exist.  I would recommend moving it to a `.YYYYMMDD.HHMMSS` extension or something.

**NOTE:** In threaded logging operations, even if the new file has been opened, you may have to wait a bit for all of the threads to switch to the new logging stream.  I'm not sure how Snort works but I have seen the `log.YYYYMMDD` file growing even after the `log` file was re-opened.  I just wait a minute before I consume the renamed logfile.  FYI.

Comment: So that means, I first move/re-name the file, wait a minute that the last entries can be written and than can evaluate the data, while the snort app will create a new file with the old name and add new entries. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes that should work.  You might be better with: rename the file, watch for the new file to be created by Snort, wait a minute, process old file.